# Create new line for each Listbox selection in a multiselect

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a form with a few textboxes and one listbox. In the listbox, you can multiselect the months.

I'd like:

1. If you select more than one month, to add a new row with the data from the textboxes and the month.
   E.g. If you choose January and February, create two new rows (below the last row that already has a value in it).
2. In column A, the selected month should appear, but not written as in the listbox (e.g. January), but the current year and the number of the month -> 202201 (for January), 202202 (for February) etc.

I'm using this code to add a new row for the other data:
So based on row 3.

```
last = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

And I have this code for the Listbox:

```vb
Dim i As Integer
With Exceptions.Listmonths

For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
    If .Selected(i) Then
    
        If Cells(last, 2).Value = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 2).Value = .List(i)
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 2).Value = .List(i)
        End If
    
    Else
    
    End If
    
Next i

End With
```

This adds one row below (based on row 3).

How I can implement that in VBA?

Only alternative I found was to have optionbuttons with each month, but that means I have to click on the submit button to add the data to the file every time for each month.

Comment: What event triggers the code to execute ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly ....

[image]

If the animation above is similar with your case, then maybe you can modify the code below to meet your case :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ListMonths.List = [index(text(column(a:L)*29,"mmmm"),,)]
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim YM As String: Dim i As Integer

'change if needed
LR = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With Exceptions.ListMonths
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            YM = "01-" & .List(i) & "-2020"
            YM = Format(Date, "yyyy") & Format(YM, "mm")
            ActiveSheet.Cells(LR, 1).Value = YM
            LR = LR + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

The initialize sub populates the ListMonths Listbox.
The CommandButton1_Click sub gets the last row as LR variable, then create a string in a date format with the month/s selected in ListMonths as YM variable, then format the YM variable with current year as yyyy and the month/s selected as two digit number. Then put the YM value into the last row.